# How to send push notifications windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, push-notification

I am new in windows phone.Iam developing one app.in this app  I want to send  pushnotifications.how to send and receive  pushnotifications in windows phone 8 using c#.please help me.

```
public string SendNotificationToWindows(string message, string notificationId)
        {
            try
            {

                //string subscriptionUri = "http://db3.notify.live.net/throttledthirdparty/01.00/AwYAAACKB3Noan4l%2bojXM5%2f3TDodPTegXbZxtTAzRktj3eWFOYmjjN1FPIdkuduXrwYZByFKLxy1gXy8rCmf1FSM6GH92rva7ecbQ%2b1%2bnGYxLWxoAI0GL03fZbV29p%2fu%2fJYrHQI%3d";
                 string subscriptionUri = "http://db3.notify.live.net/throttledthirdparty/01.00/aHR0cHM6Ly9zaW4ubm90aWZ5LndpbmRvd3MuY29tLz90b2tlbj1Bd1lBQUFEQjE1TzJMQWMlMmZBQldlUlpQendHMlglMmJRNWlPbzVUOVF3UUtXeUFQJTJic2clMmZFREhuSHM0bDBVN2tFN2prSXVJYU1hWEZIdmJYR2t6cEpQJTJiaCUyYldJSVJFTjBSd244TzJRNFV5RUs0OFJKZDdLSWJPeXVUMXFNWVNwa0Y3bmlBak5kZmslM2Q=";

                //string subscriptionUri = "https://hk2.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAACKB3Noan4l%2bojXM5%2f3TDodPTegXbZxtTAzRktj3eWFOYmjjN1FPIdkuduXrwYZByFKLxy1gXy8rCmf1FSM6GH92rva7ecbQ%2b1%2bnGYxLWxoAI0GL03fZbV29p%2fu%2fJYrHQI%3d";


                //string subscriptionUri = "http://sn1.notify.live.net/throttledthirdparty/01.00/aHR0cHM6Ly9zaW4ubm90aWZ5LndpbmRvd3MuY29tLz90b2tlbj1Bd1lBQUFEckVzRmdhR2phMXQ1aVo5MGdvRzAzejR5cE1SJTJiMHIwR2ZQc0Q0U0xzYnJOY2V3JTJmdU5pek1kZER4ZG9UdE5CM05PbjQ4dU9yUktzakN0U2JJa2lObmdBQVljQzdScDZ0blRBZlBDWjB4OWlZMDJRSDF3JTJieHM1ZzVMSTlWSXdGZWslM2Q=";

              //  string subscriptionUri = "https://sin.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAADrEsFgaGja1t5iZ90goG03z4ypMR%2b0r0GfPsD4SLsbrNcew%2fuNizMddDxdoTtNB3NOn48uOrRKsjCtSbIkiNngAAYcC7Rp6tnTAfPCZ0x9iY02QH1w%2bxs5g5LI9VIwFek%3d";




                var sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri);

                // Create an HTTPWebRequest that posts the toast notification to the Microsoft Push Notification Service.
                // HTTP POST is the only method allowed to send the notification.
                sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

                // The optional custom header X-MessageID uniquely identifies a notification message. 
                // If it is present, the same value is returned in the notification response. It must be a string that contains a UUID.
                // sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-MessageID", "<UUID>");

                // Create the toast message.
                var toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                   "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                      "<wp:Toast>" +
                           "<wp:Text1>" + message + "</wp:Text1>" +
                      "</wp:Toast> " +
                   "</wp:Notification>";
                // Set the notification payload to send.
                byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toastMessage);

                // Set the web request content length.
                sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
                sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
                sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
                sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");


                using (var requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
                }

                // Send the notification and get the response.
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
                var notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
                var notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
                var deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

                // Display the response from the Microsoft Push Notification Service.  
                // Normally, error handling code would be here. In the real world, because data connections are not always available,
                // notifications may need to be throttled back if the device cannot be reached.
                var rep = notificationStatus + " | " + deviceConnectionStatus + " | " + notificationChannelStatus;
                return rep;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
                // TextBoxResponse.Text = "Exception caught sending update: " + ex.ToString();
            }
```

this is my service I am sending on uri to this service,but I don't know whenever came to response it will throw exeception"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."but i dont know what type of uri will give.in this uri with send one key but which type of key will send please anyone reply me

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: yes @glorfindel. but I couldn't find any useful answer.please give me any  sample example

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow? And where did it go wrong?

Comment: @glorfindel. please find the above code

Comment: You're better off using a public library like PushSharp (like @Rohit suggests below.) Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: If you don't mind please do accept the answer, if it solved your problem, so that it  would be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could check out [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) It appears to have been updated for the new notification payload formats in Windows Phone 8. [Here](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/PushSharp.Sample/Program.cs) is the server code for sending Push Notifications from a Server and in this [link](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/tree/master/Client.Samples/PushSharp.ClientSample.WindowsPhone/PushSharp.ClientSample.WindowsPhone) you can find the implementation for the Windows Phone.

Basically, there are two types of Push notification your app may be using in Windows Phone 8.1.

1. [MPNS: Microsoft Push Notification Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
2. [WNS: Windows Notification Service.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx)

MPNS is the old style notification service used in Windows Phone 7 and 8.  WNS is the Windows 8 style notification which is available to Applications specifically targeting Windows Phone 8.1.  (Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 apps and Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows runtime) apps.

PushSharp appears to support both types of notification services, MPNS in the `PushSharp.WindowsPhone` libraries and WNS in the `PushSharp.Windows` libraries.

Also it might be worth checking out Azure for the same. 
Here is a tutorial for the same => [Send push notifications to authenticated users](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-push-notifications-app-users/)

Comment: thanks rohit but i couldn't find any link in above PushSharp it will show empty page.please give me  sample code.actually I am using windows runtime not silverlight template.

Comment: Please find the updates to the answer. Or else check this link => https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/Client.Samples/PushSharp.ClientSample.WindowsPhone/PushSharp.ClientSample.WindowsPhone/PushSharpClient.cs

Answer (score 2):

Below are the steps needed for [push notification for windows phone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx) .

1. Your app requests a push notification URI from the Push client service.
2. The Push client service negotiates with the Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS), and MPNS returns a notification URI to the Push client service.
3. The Push client service returns the notification URI to your app.
4. Your app can then send the notification URI to your cloud service.
5. When your cloud service has info to send to your app, it uses the notification URI to send a push notification to MPNS.
6. MPNS routes the push notification to your app.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202970(v=vs.105).aspx) MSDN page  to understand push notification in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to send notification manually with the following code:

```
void SendToastMessage(string pushUri, string message)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request =
                (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pushUri);
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("X-MessageID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            request.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");
            request.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
            string toastMessage = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                          <wp:Notification
                              xmlns:wp=""WPNotification"">
                              <wp:Toast>
                                <wp:Text1>{0}</wp:Text1>
                                <wp:Text2>{1}</wp:Text2>
                              </wp:Toast>
                          </wp:Notification>";
            string toastXml = string.Format(toastMessage,
                                  "sample:",
                                  message);
            byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toastXml);
            request.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(notificationMessage,
                          0,
                          notificationMessage.Length);
            }
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response =
                (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

This code worked perfectly fine to me a year earlier and it still does. But make sure your pushUri is correct.

Comment: thanks @deeiip but what type of pushuri will send I don't know will u please explain.please give me any  sample uri